# Detect user mobile device on Facebook graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way of detecting the user mobile device or at least know if the user is also using Facebook on a mobile device?

Comment: Where does your application sit in the flow? It is unclear from the question where your application is executing and whether you are looking for information on the specific user of the application or are you consuming a Graph API response and looking for mobile details in the response JSON.

Comment: When making a graph API request to Facebook to get my friends' details, I would like to know who is using Facebook from a mobile and also if it possible to know if it is from an Android or iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the Mobile Device Filtering section on the below url:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/custom-muti-friend-selector/

You should do a Graph API request like the below:

GET https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/?field=devices

Just want to add that the `field` parameter didn't work for me, but `fields` works. So you can try the below url alternatively (I would suggest to try it first).

GET https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/?fields=devices

And do not forget you will need an access_token

GET https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/?field=devices&access_token=....

Comment: Thanks! I have already managed with this thing about a month ago. But the urls you sent are good and relevant. You can have a look at my app that use this feature: http://app2gift.com

Comment: @bashan Please share your solution